# Possible action_types for Facebook Ads API conversions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm looking for a list of all the possible values for the action_type conversion attribute when making calls to https://graph.facebook.com/(AD_GROUP_ID)/conversions and was unable to find one in the Facebook Ads API documentation.

Does anybody know where I could find that? We're building an application that will be used by various ad agencies and it would therefore be helpful to see what are all the different values we can expect to get once the application is in production.

Thanks!

Comment: which one can't you find? if it's one of the default/built-ins it should be documented, but they can be effectively arbitrary because in-app actions are supported by [action spec](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/intro-action-specs/)

Comment: Just to make sure I get this right, you're saying that ads could have custom "action_type" values since users can specify their own actions... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you can use action spec to target, promote or track conversions based on any action type supported by Open Graph as well as the built-in actions like 'page_like', 'page_engagement', etc. For example, you can consider it a trackable conversion if someone sees your ad then listens to 'Danger Zone' on Spotify by including this in your tracking spec: `{'action.type': 'music.listens', 'song': 'http://open.spotify.com/track/2RtnoUsvJg3wMgMeEhG6fr' }`